# issue with using super()

Tags: java, super

I'm getting the Syntax errors 
"Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token" 
and 
"Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block" after I use the super() keyword in my Customer class. I've looked around on other forum posts concerning this but I already have super() as the first thing in my Customer class. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main 
{
public class Customer 
{
   public String Name = "";
   public int ID = 0000;
   public int plansLeft = 0;


   public Customer()
    {
    }

   public Customer (String n, int id, int pl) 
   {
      Name = n;
      ID = id;
      plansLeft = pl;
   }
   public void setName(String n)
   {
      Name = n;  
   }
   public void setidnumber(int id)
   {
       ID = id;
   } 
   public void setdepartmen(int pl)
   {
       plansLeft = pl;
   }


   public String getName()
   {
      return Name;
   }
   public int getIDNumber()
   {
      return ID;
   }
   public int getPlansLeft()
   {
      return plansLeft;
   }
}


public class Session extends Customer 
{
    super(Name, ID, plansLeft);    // <------------------------- issue is here

    public int sessionIDNumber = 0000;
    public int spotsLeft = 0;

    public Session()
    {
    }

    public Session (int cID, int sl) 
       {
        sessionIDNumber = cID;
        spotsLeft = sl;
       }

    public int getsessionIDNumber() {
        return sessionIDNumber;
    }

    public int getspotsLeft() {
        return spotsLeft;
    }

    public void setsessionIDNumber(int sessionIDNumber) {
        this.sessionIDNumber = sessionIDNumber;
    }

    public void setspotsLeft(int sl) {
        this.spotsLeft = sl;
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Session session = new Session(0117, 1);
    Customer customer = new Customer("Sarah", 12345678, 12);

    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + customer.getName() + "\nCustomer ID: " + customer.getIDNumber() + "\nLessons Remaining: " + customer.getPlansLeft());
    System.out.println("\nSession ID: " + session.getsessionIDNumber() + "\nOpen Spots Available: " + session.getspotsLeft());
}
}
```

Comment: **not** first line of *class*, first line of *constructor*

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate when the linked post doesn't have the same error message as me? These responses have just confused me more than I was already and now my question won't get as many views/answers anymore.

Comment: You don't need any more views. The duplicate explains how to use super and that is your problem and the reason for the error -- you don't know. And your question has already been answered

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass some value to super class constructor. And you should call super as first line after constructor

It should look something like this

```
public Session (int cID, int sl, String Name, int id, int plansLeft) 
   {
    super(Name, id, plansLeft);
    sessionIDNumber = cID;
    spotsLeft = sl;
   }
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

Customer customer = new Customer(0117, 1, "Sarah", 12345678, 12);

System.out.println("Customer Name: " + customer.getName() + "\nCustomer ID: " + customer.getIDNumber() + "\nLessons Remaining: " + customer.getPlansLeft());
System.out.println("\nSession ID: " + customer.getsessionIDNumber() + "\nOpen Spots Available: " + customer.getspotsLeft());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
public Session() { 
  super(Name, ID, plansLeft);
}
```

super() as a call to the parent constructor *must* be the first line of a child constructor.